# manual calculation of pseudo inverse is not same as pinv in matlab

Tags: matlab

I had a matrix D which is m*n and i am calculating the pseudo inverse using the formula inv(D'*D)*D' but it is not generating the same result as pinv(D).I need the term inv(D'*D) which i require for incremental operation. My all accuracy depends upon inv(D'*D) which is not correct. Is there any alternate way to get inv(D'*D) accurately? can any one help me please?

% D is 3x4 matrix that i had copied from one blog just for demonstration purpose. Actually original one of mine also had same problem bu its size is too large that i can't post it here.

```
D = -[1/sqrt(2) 1 1/sqrt(2) 0;0 1/sqrt(2) 1 1/sqrt(2);-1/sqrt(2) 0 1/sqrt(2) 1];

    B1 = pinv(D)
    B2 = D'*inv(D*D')

    B1 =

      -0.353553390593274   0.000000000000000   0.353553390593274
      -0.375000000000000  -0.176776695296637   0.125000000000000
      -0.176776695296637  -0.250000000000000  -0.176776695296637
       0.125000000000000  -0.176776695296637  -0.375000000000000

    Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =
    1.904842e-017. 

    B2 =

      -0.250000000000000                   0   0.500000000000000
      -0.500000000000000                   0                   0
       0.250000000000000  -0.500000000000000                   0
                       0                   0  -0.750000000000000
```

I need inv(D'D) to do incremental operation. Actually in my problem at step 1, each time a new row will be added to the last position of D and in step 2 first row of the D will be removed. So i want to find final D inverse using the inverse which i calculated before these two steps. More precisely have a look here:

```
B = inv(D'*D); % if i can calculate it accurately then further work is as follows
D1 = [D;Lr];  %Lr is last row to be added
BLr = B-((B*Lr'*Lr*B)/(1+Lr*B*Lr')); % Row addition formula
Fr = D1(1,:); % First row to be removed 
D2 = removerows(D1,1);
BFr = BLr+ ((BLr*Fr'*Fr*BLr)/(1-Fr*BLr*Fr')); % row deletion formula
B = BFr;
Y = BFr*D2;
```

Comment: The warning should not be ignored. Taking the inverse of an ill conditioned matrix is a recipe for disaster.  My advice: avoid the `inv ()` function at all costs. It is almost never the right thing to do.  `pinv ()` and the backslash operator are usually a better choice.

Comment: What algorithm are you using?  I don't really have the time to reverse-engineer your Matlab code.  Also, is it possible that lines 3 and 6 should read "`BLr = B-((B'*Lr'*Lr*B)/(1+Lr*B*Lr'));`" and "`BFr = BLr+((BLr'*Fr'*Fr*BLr)/(1-Fr*BLr*Fr'));`" respectively (missing a transpose in each?  B is square, so the matrix multiply will still work, but it seems like an unusual formulation in its current state.

Comment: thanks #nispio. Actually i tried to go with "B = (pinv(D'*D))*D' " but this one too is not exactly same as pinv(D). Another thing there is no transpose missing. I need D2 inverse using B just to avoid inverse operation so that overall time could be saved. In line 3 i have not multiplied with transpose because in that case BLr is the element which can produce BFr. After this i had done transpose multiplication in Y.

Answer (score 4):

The formulae (D^T D)^-1 D^T or D^T (D D^T)^-1 you are using for the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse are only valid if D has full column or full row rank, respectively.

This is not true in your case, as the warning "Matrix is close to singular" shows.

The matlab pinv command works for arbitrary D, even if the matrix has neither full row or full column rank.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I need to forward a matrix which is neither a rank deficit but still above problem is coming. That matrix is basically a square matrix which i want to analyze through (D'*D)*D' for some specific purpose. can you tell me your email id where i can forward you that matrix which is of 50*50 size.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `cond(D)` on your matrix and see what the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) is. The higher the number, the more ill-conditioned your matrix is. Similarly, you can run `cond(D'*D)`. A matrix can be full rank and still be ill-conditioned.  On paper, an ill-conditioned matrix is still invertible. However, when you attempt to directly invert an ill-conditioned matrix on a computer, small precision errors caused by quantization and other effects can cause wildly undpredictable results in the solution.

For the above stated reason, there is usually a better way (more numerically stable) to achieve what you are after than to compute the inverse directly.  Many of these involve matrix decomposotion techniques such as [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  If you help us understand *why* you need `inv(D'*D)` it would be easier to point you in the direction of the appropriate alternative.  For example, if you just need the pseudo-inverse, go ahead and use `pinv()`, even though it differs from your result using `inv()`. The `pinv()` function and the `\ (mldivide)` [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) are much more numerically stable tools than `inv()`.

Comment: condition no for my matrix D is coming out to be 5.647354603596872e+010. why i need inv(D'D) i had stated at the top. please suggest some good way to sort my problem out.

Comment: @PrabhankarPorwal: if D has not full row or column rank as in your case, the D'D or DD' is not invertible (as i already said). So whether or not you need inv(D'D) doesnt matter, it doesnt exist. So your update approach cannot work. You have to think about why D is singular, as nispio already said.

Comment: # Andreas H. I told you my D is not as the one specified in my question.i know its(specified D in above question) rank is 2 which is neither full row or column rank . My actual D is of 50*50 (which i can not post in my question) whose rank is also 50. but condition no is  5.647354603596872e+010. D in above question i posted just to demonstrate my problem. if u want my D, i can forward it to you. please mention your email id.

Comment: @PrabhankarPorwal: I understand that. But a condition number of 1e10 is a clear indication for a singular matrix, so your 50x50 D is singular as well. From looking at the matrix we cant tell why it is singular. That you have to figure out from how the matrix D is created or where it originates.

Comment: Thanks Andreas & nispio for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

See the official documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html .

If A x ~ b, the solution `x = pinv(A) * b` produces the minimum-norm solution, but `x = A\b` doesn't.  See the numerical example at the link above.